# Quiero hacer un select de una tabla que tiene dos veces la misma llave foranea

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

Necesito ayuda con una base de datos que estoy realizando para un proyecto de autobuses y rutas,
Tengo la tabla Tbl_lugares(id,lugares) y una tabla que se llama Tbl_rutas(id,Origen(lugares),Destino(lugares)) necesito hacer un select para mostrar cuales son las rutas y destinos que ahi pero al querer hacerlo me encuentro con el problema de no poder mostrar los datos, pues no se como mostrar la información de la llave foránea 2 veces

Lo he intentado de esta forma

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradecería mucho su ayuda, soy nuevo aquí

Comment: Por favor tu consulta como texto

Comment: La segunda foto, edita y pon el código en texto. Por otro lado, porque tienes una clave foránea repetida? Te aconsejo que leas los 4 primeros puntos de las leyes de codd y que mires el modelo entidad relación a tablas para hacer una DB correctamente.

Answer (score 1):

La consulta que debes hacer incluye dos inner join a la tabla tbl_lugares

```
select  origen.Lugares as Origen,
        dest.Lugares as Destino, 
from tbl_Rutas rt
join tbl_lugares origen on rt.LugarOrigen = origen.idLugares
join tbl_lugares dest on rt.LugarDestino = dest.idLugares
```